# Binding QML ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy wiht a C++ model in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I’m working on a project where I need to visualize a 3D surface using Qt. The data for the surface is stored in a `cv::Mat` in a C++ model, and I’m trying to bind this model to a `ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy` in QML.

Here's my C++ model:

```
class MyTableModel: public QAbstractTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    enum Roles {
        PixelRole = Qt::UserRole + 1
    };

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;

    MyTableModel(const cv::Mat& data, QObject* parent = nullptr);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex()) const override;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex& index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;

private:
    cv::Mat m_dataMatrix;
};
```

The `Q_PROPERTY` is defined as follows in another `Q_OBJECT`:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractTableModel* myModel READ getMyModel NOTIFY dataChanged)

private:
MyTableModel* getMyModel() { return m_myModel; }
MyTableModel* m_myModel;
```

And here's my QML code:

```
Surface3D 
{
    anchors.fill:parent
    Surface3DSeries 
    {
        ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy 
        {
            itemModel: pageModel.myModel;
            rowRole: "x"
            columnRole: "y"
            zPosRole: "PixelValue"
         }
     }
}
```

When I start the application, the 3D surface is empty and no data are displayed. I suspect there might be an issue in fetching data from the backend model. I’m not sure if the roles I’ve set are correct.

I’ve found online resources on how to set the Surface3D with a `HeightMapSurfaceDataProxy` or with a `ListModel` directly built in QML, but none explain how to build a model in C++ and bind it with QML.

If needed, I can upload the method implementations of the `MyTableModel` class.

Here the implementation of data method:

```
QVariant MyTableModel::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid() || role != MyTableModel::Roles::PixelRole)
        return QVariant();

    float value = dataMatrix.at<float>(index.row(), index.column());

    return QVariant(value);
}
```

Comment: There is this [demo](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtdatavis3d-qmlsurfacegallery-example.html) where they use a `HeightMapSurfaceDataProxy` which basically gets a PNG. You might be able to provide a `QByteArray` generated from your `cv::Mat` in a similar fashion.

Comment: To better understand your issue you would need to share the implementation of your `data()` function.

Comment: Sure, I have uploaded the method's implementation

Comment: It's weird to me that your getter function (getMyModel) is private.

Comment: The function `getMyModel()` is used by `Q_PROPERTY` to access the model through QML. It is not used by any other C++ code.

Comment: I think `x` and `y` are no roles in your table model, so the mapping doesn't resolve. Also your role is called `PixelRole` and you map to `PixelValue` in your QML code. How does your [`roleNames()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#roleNames) function look like? This is needed to map the enum to QML. That said, I would use `QSurfaceDataArray` as shown in the oscilloscope demo I've shared above instead of a table model. If you need help with that I can create you a small example.

Comment: I map the `PixelRole` with `PixelValue` in this way: `roles[PixelRole] = "PixelValue";`
If you could provide me with a small example it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is using [`QSurfaceDataProxy`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.5/qsurfacedataproxy.html) to provide the [`Surface3DSeries`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.5/qml-qtdatavisualization-surface3dseries.html) with data. The constructor of `MatData` which is derived from `QSurfaceDataProxy` contains the creation of a `cv::Mat` with random data and maps it to a `QSurfaceDataArray`. The key here is the call to [`resetArray()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsurfacedataproxy.html#resetArray) which will replace the `QSurface3DSeries` of the `QSurfaceDataProxy` with the provided data.

I'm using Qt 6.5.4 hence the import for `Surface3D` and `Surface3DSeries` is QtDataVisualization instead of QtGraphs. If you use Qt 6.6 or higher you can adapt the imports.

There is a small hack in the constructor which is a workaround for the following issue reported in [QTBUG-58884](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58884), [QTBUG-65322](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65322) and [QTBUG-103965](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-103965). The last bugreport had a comment with the workaround I'm using.

You can find the full source code for the example over [here](https://github.com/iam-peter/stackoverflow/tree/main/questions/77825378).

```
MatData::MatData(QObject *parent)
    : QSurfaceDataProxy(parent)
{
    // Create a cv::Mat to be used as surface
    cv::Mat test(20, 20, CV_32F);
    cv::Mat mean = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 1, CV_32F);
    cv::Mat sigma = cv::Mat::ones(1, 1, CV_32F);
    sigma.at<float>(0, 0, 0) = 10;

    cv::RNG rng;
    rng.fill(test, cv::RNG::NORMAL, mean, sigma);

    cv::Mat mat;
    blur(test, mat, cv::Size(5, 5));

    m_dataArray = new QSurfaceDataArray;
    m_dataArray->reserve(mat.rows);

    for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; i++) {
        QSurfaceDataRow *newProxyRow = new QSurfaceDataRow(mat.cols);
        m_dataArray->append(newProxyRow);

        for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++) {
            QSurfaceDataItem &item = (*newProxyRow)[j];
            item.setPosition(QVector3D(i, mat.at<float>(i, j), j));

            // https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-103965
            auto tmp = (*newProxyRow)[j];
            tmp.setPosition(QVector3D(tmp.z(), tmp.y(), tmp.x()));
            (*newProxyRow)[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

    resetArray(m_dataArray);
}
```

```
import QtQuick
import QtDataVisualization
import CustomProxy

Window {
    width: 800
    height: 600
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColorGradient {
        id: surfaceGradient
        ColorGradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "black" }
        ColorGradientStop { position: 0.2; color: "red" }
        ColorGradientStop { position: 0.5; color: "blue" }
        ColorGradientStop { position: 0.8; color: "yellow" }
        ColorGradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "white" }
    }

    Surface3D {
        id: surfaceGraph
        anchors.fill: parent

        Surface3DSeries {
            id: surfaceSeries
            flatShadingEnabled: false
            drawMode: Surface3DSeries.DrawSurface | Surface3DSeries.DrawWireframe
            baseGradient: surfaceGradient
            colorStyle: Theme3D.ColorStyleRangeGradient
            itemLabelFormat: "(@xLabel, @zLabel): @yLabel"

            MatData {}
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the application]